# Exclude Database entries based on a value in SQL While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop, ssms

I have been tasked with editing a stored Procedure in  SQL Management Studio. I have done what was required, but a by-product of that is that now the records are being populated with data that isnt needed. I am looking to exclude data based on a variable LINE_CD and want to filter (recieve) data that is  LINE_CD <=14 OR LINE_CD = 21.

Currently I have edited other records to ask for LINE_CD <=14 OR LINE_CD = 21, but there is a while loop, which uses  a variable "MAXLINECD" which is set at 21. (This used to be 14, representing the lines we had, now a new line has been added) I only want all LINE_CD <= 14 OR LINE_CD = 21.

The loop is:

```
DECLARE @Index int, @LINE_CD int, @ORDER int
SELECT @LINE_CD = 1, @ORDER = 51
WHILE @LINE_CD <= @MAX_LINE_CD
    BEGIN
```

Can I write something like:

```
DECLARE @Index int, @LINE_CD int, @ORDER int
SELECT @LINE_CD = 1, @ORDER = 51
WHERE @LINE_CD =1, @ORDER = 51 not in 
    (SELECT @LINE_CD, @ORDER WHERE LINE_CD <=14 OR LINE_CD = 21)
WHILE @LINE_CD <= @MAX_LINE_CD
  BEGIN
```

To give me just the LINE_CD's: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 & 21?

Comment: My guess is you don't actually need to use a loop here at all. Loops are horribly inefficient in sql server and can almost always be replaced by set based logic that is not only faster but easier to maintain because it is far less complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `WHERE` because you aren't selecting a set from a table.   You can evaluate the condition in the `WHILE` loop.

```
DECLARE @Index int, @LINE_CD int, @ORDER int
SELECT @LINE_CD = 1, @ORDER = 51
WHILE @LINE_CD <= @MAX_LINE_CD
    BEGIN
    IF @LINE_CD <=14 OR @LINE_CD = 21
        BEGIN
```